# Null sequence and a bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How would i tackle this question?

Let (an)n∈N+ be a null sequence and let (bn)n∈N+be a bounded sequence. Prove that (anbn)n∈N+ is a null sequence.

obviously need to use the product rule..

Comment: Hint: $|a_n b_n|\le M|a_n |$, where $M$ is an upper bound of the $|b_n|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M>0$ such that

$$|b_n|\le M,\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N$$
and let $\epsilon >0$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ then there's $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\forall n\ge n_0$ we have $|a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}M$
hence we get

$$\forall n\ge n_0\implies |a_nb_n|<\frac{\epsilon}M\times M=\epsilon$$
hence the desired result.